# Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

this is my typescript

```
export class State {
  constructor(public name: string, public population: string, public flag: string) { }
}



export class AutocompleteOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
      stateCtrl: FormControl;
      filteredStates: Observable<any[]>;
    temp:string;
      states: State[] = [
        {
          name: 'Arkansas',
          population: '2.978M',
          // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Arkansas.svg
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/Flag_of_Arkansas.svg'
        },
        {
          name: 'California',
          population: '39.14M',
          // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_California.svg
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Flag_of_California.svg'
        },
        {
          name: 'Florida',
          population: '20.27M',
          // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Florida.svg
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Florida.svg'
        },
        {
          name: 'Texas',
          population: '27.47M',
          // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Texas.svg
          flag: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Flag_of_Texas.svg'
        }
      ];

      constructor() {
        this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();

      }
   ngOnInit() {
        this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(state => state ? this.filterStates(state) : this.states.slice(),
        )
        );
      }

      filterStates(name1:string) {
        return this.states.filter(state =>
          state.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name1.toLowerCase()) === 0);
      }
```

i am getting error like ** Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.** on ngOnInit function i am calling this.filterStates(state) function but i am getting error please help he

Comment: Remove the call to `startWith`.

Comment: after removeing startwith still it is not working.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to accomplish but your `startWith` is going to result in `Observable<string | State>`

Comment: this is an example in angular material autcomplete so i want to know where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 2):

you can  change the  type of 'val' variable from 'string' to 'any' and it should work.

`filter(val: any): string[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()));
  }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but could be because your filterStates function is receiving an string:

```
filterStates(name1:string) {
  ...
}
```

but you are passing an object:

```
map(state => state ? this.filterStates(state)
```

Comment: state is value of map so it is not an object,State is class and states is an object.

Comment: i am doing this example:"https://stackblitz.com/angular/rmnkqxeeqxl?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.ts".

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code in the stackblitz and I'm not getting any error. Be sure you have all the dependencies included and all the imports

Comment: getting error like this   **ERROR in D:/mobicable/src/app/component/shared/autocomplet.component.ts (55,48): Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
ERROR in D:/mobicable/src/app/component/shared/autocomplet.component.ts (55,48): Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.**